# Is the code produced by JS eval better faster than if I parse the string by hand?

Tags: javascript, performance, eval

Javascript's eval is arguably evil, but has anyone benchmarked the resulting code: is it faster (more efficient in any other way ?) than if I parse the input string using one of the JS parsers such as [jsep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsep) or [rd_parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rd-parse) and compile the resulting AST by hand?

Comment: Modern JavaScript engines are super fast. I highly doubt any library would do better than the native engine.

Comment: I don't doubt that. I am just wondering by how much. Is it orders of magnitude or something like 10-20% ? It is a valid question. I am surprised it is downvoted. I should probably give a bit more context here. I am already using a parser to build the AST for my input, and I have to evaluate it bit by bit to extract the types of the various parts of the formula, and introduce wrappers around some of the classes. So in the end I end up with a complete evaluator compiled by hand. Should I just throw it away and re-run eval on the whole input (modified with wrapper code) ?

Comment: I should have probably also added a disclosure that I am the author of one of the packages I mentioned in my question (rd-parse). It is however not relevant to the question.

Comment: And one more note: I am NOT interested in the performance of eval itself (it would not surprise me if it were indeed orders of magnitude faster). I am interested in the performance of the resulting code. And for this one I have reasonable doubts there would be any performance impact at all. But may be I am missing something...

Comment: How do you compile in Javascript without using `eval`?

Comment: A parser would produce an AST for your input, e.g.  smth like
{
  "type": "BinaryExpression",
  "operator": "+",
  "left": {
    "type": "Literal",
    "value": 1,
  },
  "right": {
    "type": "Identifier",
    "name": "foo"
  }
}
that you can use to compile the code yourself recursively. This is exactly what tools like [expression-eval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expression-eval) would do for you

Comment: "that you can use to compile the code yourself recursively" How? The `compile` defined there is just `evaluate.bind(null, jsep(expression))`, which isn't real compilation, and obviously produces abysmally slow code.

Comment: Well, I am not sure the authors of expression-eval did the right thing. Here's exactly what I had in mind: https://runkit.com/embed/fsgxzyfflc98
 The performance is obviously worse with the 'manual eval', and it would probably be getting slower when the expression complexity grows, but probably not "abysmally" slower :) Running this gist with node.js locally I get about twice performance boost with the "natively" eval'ed input.